# Signature pad is slow on android

Tags: android, performance

I am using Thomas J Bradley plugin for drawing signature on touch devices like ipad/xoom/galaxy... I have a simple jsp page which includes jquery and signature pad scripts

```
 $('div.signaturePadClass').signaturePad({displayOnly:false})
```

works like a charm on ipad, but it is kind a slow on android (xoom/samsung galaxy).
I checked the plugin homepage on these devices, and the demo on the home page is also slow on android.

Is there a workaround?.. fix for this? 
Or is there a better plugin out there?.
If no, then whats the reason for this slowness... is it just a slow android?

Answer (score 4):

## Environment

Unfortunately, you cannot influence the way android (the used web browser, did you test it on different ones?) executes javascript. You could use a 3rd party javascript engine but X8 (which uses google chrome) is said to be one of the best, already.

## Hardware

If you are using Android 3.0 or above you can enable hardware acceleration.
Add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to your manifest `application` tag to enable it.
Hopefully it may work.

## Optimize the code

A large amount of optimizations should be concerned when writing javascript for mobile devices. The two most important are:

- Do as much as possible serverside (To execute only the javascript which really is neccessary)
- Avoid manipulating the DOM (which makes javascript that slow)
- For more performance hints look [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/JavaScript_Performance_Best_Practices) and [here](http://blog.monitis.com/index.php/2011/05/15/30-tips-to-improve-javascript-performance/)